# What is the command in RMarkdown to "source" and display the code from an existing .R file?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Example: My R script is named "code.R". It produces a simple plot of y versus x. And looks like this in Rmarkdown.

`````
    ````{r eval=FALSE}
    ## code in "code.R"
    x = 1:10
    y = 1:10
    plot(x,y)
    ```
`````

For documentation and reproducibility I want to create a Rmarkdown file which reads "code.R" when knitted from RStudio. (A bit like *\include{}* in LaTex.) The resulting RMarkdown PDF should thus display a not-evaluated verbatim copy of the R code from "code.R".

The end goal is to make a RMarkdown file which reads dozens of R-files and groups all R-code in one PDF for reproducibility and future reference. This would prevent me to copy-paste the new R code each time I alter the source files.  I am not interested in actually running the R-code in RMarkdown.

Part of a solution (but how?) might be to create a chunk which read the file and stores the read textlines and another chunk which displays these text lines as verbatim code?

Is there an existing build-in RMarkdown command or additional options in *````{r eval=FALSE}* which produce my intended result? Could you provide an example?

A link to a more complicated Stackoverflow question which addresses my problem indirectly is also appreciated.

Any pointers would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you seen the [spin](http://deanattali.com/2015/03/24/knitrs-best-hidden-gem-spin/) feature of knitr, which doesn't do exactly what you're asking but does allow one to turn an R script into a .Rmd file. Adding the line `#+ eval = FALSE` would allow it to be non-evaluated chunks.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast. I added this to my code.R
       #' ---
       #' title: "code.R"
       #' author: "Daniel"
       #' date: "June 8th, 2015"
#' output: md_document
#' ---
#+ eval = FALSE

Then in the R console I ran: rmarkdown::render("code.R") 
This yielded the file "code.md"
However, now I fail in loading the information in "input.md" into my Rmarkfile script.....

Comment: if you're willing to build a pipeline of sorts, I have used GPP for this

Comment: I must admit I do not know what GPP is. I do not mind making an R-script which contains the names of all other scripts of interest and than create dozens of .md files and then connect them to getter. If I knew how. My problem is that knitr/Rmarkdown looks simple but is complex when you try to go beyond "simple" examples on the internet or default settings. Steep learning curve for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found on: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/

Start your input.R script with the comment "## ---- input.R" (without the quotes)

Make an .Rmd script with the following code and Knit it. It will show the content of the input.R script in the resulting PDF.

````
      ---
      output: pdf_document
      ---

      ```{r cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
      knitr::read_chunk('input.R')
      ```

      ```{r input.R, eval=FALSE}

      ```
````