# Embed but don't run R scripts in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I am writing a paper in Rmarkdown about an ongoing project. I have my own  `.Rmd` file where I am writing it.

At the same time, I have several scripts in R stored in different files with the extension `.R`.

In different parts of the paper I need to describe what it is in those R scripts, so that I need to embed the codes of the scripts in the Rmarkdown file without running it.

To summarize:

- Folder 1

  - paper.Rmd
  - script1.R
  - script2.R

I tried this chunk with no success:

````
```{r eval=F}
source("script1.R")
````

Comment: So you mean echo the code in them without evaluating it?

Comment: This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706967/what-is-the-command-in-rmarkdown-to-source-and-display-the-code-from-an-existi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `readLines` on the script instead of sourcing it.

Consider this trivial R script:

```
writeLines("foo <- function(x) x + 2", con = "foo.R")
system("cat foo.R")
# foo <- function(x) x + 2
```

Instead of using `source` use `readLines`.

```
exp <- readLines("foo.R")
```

Now you have the text of the Rscript. You could use `cat` to print it.

```
cat(exp)
#foo <- function(x) x + 2
```

Or you could evaluate it.

```
eval(parse(text=exp))
foo(2)
#[1] 4
```