# Remove brackets and hashes when printing code from read_line() function in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I am embeding [R scripts without running them in a RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486266/embed-but-dont-run-r-scripts-in-rmarkdown/) file.

When I embed a script in R in my Rmarkdown file without running it and I knit to PDF or HTML, every line contains two hashes and is enclosed in brackets.

I would like to remove these hashes and outer brackets.

This is the code implemented in my `.Rmd` file:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
library(readr)
script1 <- read_lines("script1.R")
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
print(script1)
```
````

And now let's see the code of `script1.R`

```
  # 1. Cargamos los paquetes necesarios ####
  library(readODS)
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  library(ggpubr)
  library(readr)

  # 2. Cargamos los datos desde el archivo de LibreOffice Calc ####
  path <- "Data/xy_coord_div.ods"

  # Creamos una lista con los datos de todos los tipos de dientes
  xy_coord <- path %>%
    ods_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map(read_ods, skip = 1, path = path)
```

When I knit the `.Rmd` file to HTML, I see that code in this way:

```
##  [1] "  # 1. Cargamos los paquetes necesarios ####"                                             
##  [2] "  library(readODS)"                                                                       
##  [3] "  library(dplyr)"                                                                         
##  [4] "  library(purrr)"                                                                         
##  [5] "  library(tidyr)"                                                                         
##  [6] "  library(ggplot2)"                                                                       
##  [7] "  library(gridExtra)"                                                                     
##  [8] "  library(ggpubr)"                                                                        
##  [9] "  library(readr)"                                                                         
## [10] ""                                                                                         
## [11] "  # 2. Cargamos los datos desde el archivo de LibreOffice Calc ####"                      
## [12] "  path <- \"Data/xy_coord_div.ods\""                                                      
## [13] ""                                                                                         
## [14] "  # Creamos una lista con los datos de todos los tipos de dientes"                        
## [15] "  xy_coord <- path %>%"                                                                   
## [16] "    ods_sheets() %>%"                                                                     
## [17] "    set_names() %>%"                                                                      
## [18] "    map(read_ods, skip = 1, path = path)"                                                 
## [19] ""
```

You can also see that extra symbols are written when it deals with inner brackets.

How can I style the code when converting to other formats?

Comment: Do you want `cat(script1)` instead or `print()`? That seems to be the suggestion in the question you already linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the chunk option `comment=''`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-comment.html) to get rid of the hashes, and use `cat()` to get rid of the brackets.

````
```{r include=FALSE}
script1 <- readLines("script1.R")
```

```{r echo=FALSE, comment=''}
cat(script1, sep = '\n')
```
````

Or in one step with [`xfun::file_string()`](https://yihui.org/xfun/):

````
```{r echo=FALSE, comment=''}
xfun::file_string("script1.R")
```
````